# Tomboy in the indicator bar in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, taskbar, tomboy

Once (with the old ubuntu 12.04lts and old gnome) I had Tomboy as a icon in what I think was called indicator bar (top bar). Now with gnome 3 no icon is shown in the top bar, how can I have Tomboy on that bar as before?